# DELETE rows from multiple tables with JOIN in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I know dozen of questions are available here but I have specific issue which I didn't resolve

I have two tables `user_bookmarks` and `highlights`.

`user_bookmarks` contains all the users bookmarks and `highlights` contains the selected text of particular bookmark.

suppose two users having same bookmarks and both  did some highlight texts.

Now `user_bookmarks` and `highlight` tables contains two rows of same `bokkmark_id`.

if one user delete that bookmark then only one row will be deleted from both tables.

I did some `query` but didn't success.

here is my query

```
 DELETE FROM user_bookmarks,highlights USING user_bookmarks
 LEFT JOIN highlights ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id =
 highlights.bookmark_id WHERE user_bookmarks.`user_id` = 39 
 AND user_bookmarks.`bookmark_id`= 1556
```

Comment: user a's bookmark on page 12 of book 1 is NOT the same as user b's bookmark on page 12 of book 1. they SHOULD be able to delete them independently.

Comment: What is you question? Do you want delete only one row from each table, or delete  all rows for this bookmark?  What's mean field bookmark_id ? is it a page number? May be is better way to do a unique bookmark instead of composite key user_id+bookmark_id

Comment: I want to delete all rows from `user_bookmarks` and single row from `highlights` table.
`bookmark_id` tends to single article and multiple user can have same article, I also given condition for selected user

Comment: Does table highlights contains user_id?

Comment: yes both table contains user_id

Comment: Does  current query deletes only one row from each table for user 39 and bookmark 1556 ? I can't get your logic  you  if you want delete users bookmark (user=39, bookmark=1556) , you have to delete all hightlights for this user and bookmark, isn't it? why do you need to delete all rows from users_bookmark and only one from hightlights?

Comment: User can create multiple categories and the bookmarks could be exist in multiple category and category id available in user_bookmarks table so that multiple rows could be in user_bookmart table for same bookmarks, but in highlights table only one row will be exist on particular user, so that I want to delete all rows from user_bookmarks and from highlight table if that bookmark is exist other wise it only should be delete from user_bookmakrs,

I don't know my `query` is right or wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75170/discussion-between-jack-and-rpc1).

Comment: chat is blocked by firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion , accourding to your logic (in comments), you need to join table using composit key `user_id,bookmark_id`

```
 DELETE user_bookmarks,highlights  FROM user_bookmarks
 LEFT JOIN highlights ON 
 user_bookmarks.bookmark_id =  highlights.bookmark_id and 
 user_bookmarks.user_id =  highlights.user_id 
WHERE user_bookmarks.user_id = 39 
 AND user_bookmarks.`bookmark_id`= 1556
```

It delets rows from all rows with  user_id=39 and bookmark_id=1556 from both tables

to **delete** rows from multiple unit to put all tables into `delete` section

Comment: sorry, I change syntax... I don't have mysql at home therefore can't check syntax